# Prevent CTRL+C terminating a 'ForwardX11 yes' SSH session on Windows

Tags: ssh

When I set `ForwardX11 yes` on client side, CTRL+C will terminate this ssh session on Windows 10.

I've tried CTRL+C in:

1. CMD
2. Powershell
3. Git bash
4. a terminal in a VSCode Remote SSH workspace.
5. a linux server console

Only last two CLIs doesn't terminate the ssh session. I can sure that if I unset `ForwardX11 yes`, everything works fine.

The version of my ssh is `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2`. I just want CTRL-C performs like what it does in a terminal of VSCode Remote SSH or in a console of Linux server with `ForwardX11 yes` setting on. Is there any way to do that?

Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\ihnfsa> ssh athena@192.168.227.131
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Last login: Thu Oct 27 17:40:29 2022 from 192.168.227.1
athena@ArchLinux1 ~
$ (CTRC+C) Connection to 192.168.227.131 closed.
PS C:\Users\ihnfsa>
```

Terminal in a VSCode Remote SSH workspace:

```
athena@ArchLinux1 ~ 
$ (CTRL+C)
athena@ArchLinux1 ~ 
$
```

**Update:**

My SSH config:

```
Host 192.168.227.131
  HostName 192.168.227.131
  User athena
  XAuthLocation "C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\xauth.exe"
  ForwardAgent yes
  ForwardX11 yes
  ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

`sshd_config` on the server side:

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
```

I've installed and enabled `xorg-xserver-xvfb`, `xorg-xauth`, `xsel` on the server, `VcXsrv` on the client.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant part of your .ssh/config for this host, and indicate how you're setting ForwardX11.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in OpenSSH_for_Windows, see https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1803. It is due to the fact that `XAuthLocation` is set in your local config.

If you remove that config, Ctrl-C should work normally, and X forwarding also, since you already have `ForwardX11Trusted` (although you should make sure that `DISPLAY` is correctly set, usually to `127.0.0.1:0`, in your environment prior to invoking SSH, from the output above I think this is not the case because of the message `X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0`).